# What does ( !'which npm' ) mean in a PHP script?

Tags: php, npm

What does `( !'which npm' )` mean in the following code?

```
if ( !'which npm' ) {
  die(
        'You need to install NPM!' . PHP_EOL
  );
}
```

Here is a link to the complete file from GITHUB: [WPBP/generator/bin/wpbp-generator](https://github.com/WPBP/generator/blob/master/bin/wpbp-generator)

Comment: Looks like a condition that will never be met (a string == true)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It checks whether a hardcoded string is *falsey*. Which will always be `false`.

This logic looks a bit meaningless. I suspect the author rather wanted to write:

```
if (!`which npm`)
```

The [backtick operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php) executes the command as shell command, which makes a bit more sense.